# Can a character benefit from multiple Ioun Stones at once?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, stacking

My goblin mystic found a few Ioun Stones (4) during the last session. I asked my DM if I could use multiple at once, she took a look at the item's description, and now we are here.

If it matters I got the Agility, Intellect, Sustenance, and Reserve stones.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Holy crap. Your character found *four* Ioun Stones in one session? Can I come play with y'all?

Comment: is a 20th level party. And magic items are very common in this campaign

Comment: Technically we found 5, but that stone got broke by some kobold soo...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Multiple orbits permitted

The [Ioun stones](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ioun-stone) (DMG, 176) have no limitations on more than one being used, so you can absolutely do that!

But they do require attunement, so unless you can attune to more than 3 items, you can only have 3 going at any given time (and no other magic items.)

Just remember that they are somewhat free floating and other creatures can target them:

> Thereafter, another creature must use an action to grasp or net the stone to separate it from you, either by making a successful attack roll against AC 24 or a successful DC 24 Dexterity (Acrobatics) check.

Comment: The name(s) is/are excaping me at the moment, but I'm fairly certain there's at least one character in 5E lore that has multiple Ioun stones in orbit, implying that, even beyond the context of the rules, this is canonically possible and even has precedent. Trying to find the name...

Comment: [Larloch](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Larloch) is an example from the lore of past editions, and he may have been who I was thinking of. While as-of-yet not directly connected to 5E lore, this at least might help set the precedent that this is at all possible to "wear" several stones at once.